# jSoup to clean webpage but leave images and newlines

Tags: android, jsoup

I am trying to use jSoup to allow a reader mode of web page inside an Android WebView.

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url,3000);
 String justTheText = doc.text();
```

Applying this to CNN for example prints out every menu and such so not really reader friendly. I would like to keep headlines and text, and not get rid of images either.  I need to render the page in an orderly way.

What I need is to keep images, but throw out extraneous stuff, and keep newlines in text.   This has to be somewhat generic so it works on different page's.

If I cannot keep the images and must just display the page as pure text at least I need a way to keep titles and newlines.  And not pull in extraneous text and links etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed not a trivial task although it's definitely possible (iOS's reading mode does a pretty good job).

You'd need to first find a way to know which elements to filter, to leave out menus for example. You could try to do this by looking at the tag name and / or class name and leave out specific tags/classes.
Next you want to process the items you do want to include: get all times with text in them (and possibly add `<br/>`'s after each line), include images, etc.

Here's something to get you started (needs Java 8):

```java
        doc.body().getAllElements().stream()
            .filter(elem -> !elem.className().toLowerCase().matches(".*(menu|header|footer|logo|nav|search|link|button|btn|ad).*"))
            .forEach(elem -> {
                if (elem.hasText()) {
                    result.append(elem.text() + "<br/>");
                }
                if (elem.tagName().equals("img")) {
                    result.append(elem.toString());
                }
        });
```